# Xamarin Android Wear - Navigation

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, wear-os

I'd like an example of a step-by-step implementation of this type of menu on Android Wear.

I can not understand the concept of this implementation

It can be in Xamarin or Java.

Documentation:

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/ui-nav-actions#java

Expectancy:

[ndroid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41CLx.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad you are enjoying Xamarin!
There's multiple ways of navigating between fragments, regardless if it's a Watch. One of them is using ViewPagers. If you look into the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide), you will find details of how to make it look really cool and fancy with small changes to the ViewPager code.

As far as examples to the Google Wear app that uses ViewPagers, you can take a look at [this](http://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/wear/GridViewPager/GridViewPager) and some of the other examples of Android wear applications. Let me know if that helps. Btw, you might have more success simply implementing that code (layout/activity_main.xml, SimpleGridPagerAdapter.cs and MainActivity.cs) in your project, than making those projects works since they're old.

Since you are looking for the usage of the android.support.wear.widget.drawer.WearableDrawerLayout, you can take a look at [this](https://github.com/bryan2894-playgrnd/SimpleWeather-Xamarin/tree/c995c32c8aca09f904ff304658733f0226114a81/SimpleWeather.Wear), particularly at the activity_main.xml. For implementing the WearableDrawerLayout, you have the following

1. WearableNavigationDrawerView that acts as the top navigation drawer
2. FrameLayout that contains your fragment
3. WearableActionDrawerView that acts as your bottom action drawer

PS: I noticed you are looking for Java examples too, this one seems very simple [example](https://github.com/AOSP8146/developers/blob/9d4c95b9ac02779aceec128cad45002bf752bc0d/samples/android/wearable/wear/WearDrawers/Wearable/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/wear/weardrawers/MainActivity.java) to follow. You just have to check the Planets.java, MainActivity.java, and activity_main.xml files in that repo

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but Slide Fragment is not the correct way to implement the menu in Android Wear and the example in Git is from Wear 1.0 which is no longer recommended by Google, I would like a following example implementation code for this documentation:

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/ui-nav-actions

I updated my question with my expectation of Menu

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Saamer, very Thanks, Unfortunately the code is advanced to my level, but I will continue studying the code to see if I can extract more content.

Comment: You should create a sample called Navigation on your github and share it! And also u can create a Pull Request here to get it added ! https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/wear